# How can I reconcile the 1 on the LHS of $\prod\limits_{i \in I}(1+x_i)=\sum\limits_{J \subseteq I}\prod _{j \in J} x_j$?

Tags: combinatorics

[Byron Schmuland used this equality in his answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5595/taking-seats-on-a-plane): $\prod _{i \in I}(1+x_i)=\sum_{J \subseteq I}\prod _{j \in J} x_j$.

I can see all the combinations being replicated on both sides of the equality, however I cannot reconcile the '1' that results from the $\prod (1+x_i)$ on left side.

Comment: Partial answer of Byron Schmuland in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5595/taking-seats-on-a-plane may help you here.

Comment: On the right side, the term that corresponds to $J=\emptyset$ is $\prod_{j\in\emptyset} x_j = 1$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$\prod_{i\in I}(1+x_i)=\sum_{J\subseteq I}\prod_{j\in J}x_j$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/844846/prod-i-in-i1x-i-sum-j-subseteq-i-prod-j-in-jx-j)

Answer (score 4):

Proving a more general formula may simplify the proof: consider the  product
$$\prod_{i\in I}(e_i+x_i)$$

By the distributive law, you have to take the product of  $x_i$s in a number of factors (the indices thereof form a subset $J$ of the  indexing set $I$) and $e_i$s in the remaining factors (their indices form the  subset $I\smallsetminus J$), in *all* possible ways, i.e. $J$ can be *any* subset of $I$, and add these products. Thus we obtain:
$$\prod_{i\in I}(e_i+x_i)=\sum_{J\subset I}\biggl(\prod_{i\in I\smallsetminus J}e_i\prod_{j\in J}x_j\biggr).$$
Now set $e_i=1$ for all $i$, and you get your formula.

Answer (score 1):

It is convenient to see this in a particular case. Suppose that $I=\{1,2,3\}$. Then$$\prod_{i\in I}(1+x_i)=(1+x_1)(1+x_2)(1+x_3)(1+x_4).$$On the other hand, the subsets of $I$ are $\emptyset$, $\{1\}$, $\{2\}$, $\{3\}$, $\{1,2\}$, $\{1,3\}$, $\{2,3\}$, and $\{1,2,3\}$. So\begin{align*}\sum_{J\subset I}\prod_{j\in J}x_j&=\prod_{j\in\emptyset}x_j+\prod_{j\in\{1\}}x_j+\prod_{j\in\{2\}}x_j+\prod_{j\in\{3\}}x_j+\prod_{j\in\{1,2\}}x_j+\prod_{j\in\{1,3\}}x_j+\prod_{j\in\{2,3\}}x_j+\prod_{j\in\{1,2,3\}}x_j\\&=1+x_1+x_2+x_3+x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_2x_3+x_1x_2x_3\text,\end{align*}which is equal to the first product.

It is easy to provide a formal proof of this equality in the general case by induction.

Comment: How is it that $\prod_{j\in \emptyset} x_j = 1$

Comment: @Al-C Who said that? It's equal to $1$.

Comment: Well unless I am mistaking, you did José, in your answer,  The first term on the right of the bottom equation shows 1 right below the specified product.

Comment: @Al-C Originally, you wrote $0$. That's why I wrote “Who said that?”. Yes, it is [equal to $1$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_(mathematics)#Empty_product).

Comment: Is there any proof of this ?

Comment: @Al-C No. It is a convention.